# Puzzling scope behaviour

Tags: python, scope, class-members

I can't seem to understand what is going on here:

```
class testclass: 

    def __init__(self): 
        print "new instance" 
    myList=[] 

if __name__ == "__main__":  

    inst1=testclass() 
    inst1.myList.append("wrong") 

    inst2=testclass() 
    inst2.myList.append("behaviour") 

    print "I get the",inst2.myList
```

The output is:

```
new instance
new instance
I get the ['wrong', 'behaviour']
```

I would have expected that the list in **inst1** knows nothing about the list in **inst2**, but somehow it looks like the scope of **myList** trascends the instantiation of the class. 
I find this very unsettling and puzzling, or am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you defined `myList` is a class attribute.

The behaviour your looking for is the one of an object attribute:

```
class testclass:
    def __init__(self): 
        print "new instance"
        self.myList = []
```

Let's try it:

```
>>> t1 = testclass()
new instance
>>> t2 = testclass()
new instance
>>> t1.myList.append(1)
>>> t2.myList.append(2)
>>> t1.myList
[1]
>>> t2.myList
[2]
```

---

If you're interested in class attributes take a look at the [Class documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects). Since classes in Python are objects too, like (almost) everything in Python, they can have their own attributes.

Answer (score 3):

The way you declared `myList` inside the class makes it a *class* attribute. if you intended to have an *instance* attribute, declare it like this and it will have the expected behavior:

```
class testclass:
    def __init__(self): 
        print "new instance" 
        self.myList=[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because that is what class attributes are for. If you want an instance variable, you need to declare it on the instance itself - usually with `self` inside a method.

Answer (score 1):

`myList` is initialised at *class* instantiation time, because it is declared in the body of the class, not at *object* instantiation time.

Such properties are then shared with instances, until a variable with the same name is created on the instance.

So, in your case, you are using each object to access the same `myList` object (and append a value to it).

Answer (score 0):

```
class testclass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.myList=[]
        print "new instance"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want myList to be an instance variable, you should define self.myList inside the init function.  Then you should get the behavior you expect.  As you have it now, I think myList is a class variable, and will be shared by all instances of the class.

Comment: It will only be shared until an assignment on an object.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment.  Aren't class variables always shared among all instances? If you had myList defined as both a class variable, and as an instance variable, they would still be distinct, and assignments on one wouldn't affect the other.  Am I missing something?

Comment: That is my point. If you assign to the variable on the instance, you can no longer use that instance to access the class variable (unless, perhaps you delete the instance variable).

Comment: True, but you can always get the class variable with the class name.  It's still there.  It's still shared.

Comment: I'm not sure in what sense you think it is shared with an object that cannot access it.

Comment: Sure you can access it.  For the code given in the question, testclass.myList gets you access to the class variable.  If you add a self.myList = [] to the init function, then instance.myList gets you the instance myList.  I'll quit bugging you...just want to make sure I'm not missing something.